# Is there a way to add a permission to an application I'm testing? (my own app)

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-manifest

My application needs that GPS is active at startup as for it to proceed. 
Iam testing the app, so I'm mocking the GPS by adding `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />` to my `AndroidManisfest.xml` file.

This works ok. But I want to keep things separate. Is it possible to add a permission at runtime when we are testing?

EDIT:

I know from the [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/security.html#arch) that:

*Android has no mechanism for granting permissions dynamically (at run-time) because it complicates the user experience to the detriment of security.*

But as a matter of testing the application, is there an alternative?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to add Android permissions at run-time. They must be specified in your manifest.

If you have a separate test application, I believe you only need to put this permission on your test application.

**EDIT** A test application is really no different to Android than a regular one in terms of permissions. I would just put the permission in your test application's manifest and not worry about it.

Comment: Ok, but putting a permission in the test application doesn't make a difference. I already tried. Thanks anyway, I guess this can't be done.

Comment: Ah I see. So you need the permission in both applications? Even if only your test application is adding the Mock Provider? Anyway, sorry I can't be of further help. I imagine this was done for security reasons.

Comment: No need for sorry, you are already been very helpful. So, I'm not using any of the Mock* classes from android testing framework. I dont know how to use them right, they are stubs, I doubt about their usefulness. Probably I'm wrong. I'm using *ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2* with *Robotium*, and doing only blackbox testing. And I'm having a painful experience with timing for checking for open dialogs, started activities. How do you usually make your tests?

Comment: From what I have heard, Robotium is a superior testing framework for UI testing. I am more of a back-end code tester for Android so I can't say that i have much experience with Robotium. In terms of the Mock android classes, you are meant to extend and implement only the methods you require in those classes for each test case. That way you can stub them out in the method you require, and exceptions are thrown for methods that wouldn't expected your tested class to call.